# Heroku cli fails on remote

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

`heroku git:remote` fails with

```
WARNING: CLI is updating
 !   Get https://d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net/master/manifest.json: dial tcp: lookup d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net: no DNS servers
error loading plugin topics
WARNING: CLI is updating
 !   Get https://d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net/master/manifest.json: dial tcp: lookup d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net: no DNS servers
error loading plugin commands
WARNING: CLI is updating
 !   Get https://d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net/master/manifest.json: dial tcp: lookup d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net: no DNS servers
WARNING: CLI is updating
 !   Get https://d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net/master/manifest.json: dial tcp: lookup d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net: no DNS servers
WARNING: CLI is updating
 !   Get https://d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net/master/manifest.json: dial tcp: lookup d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net: no DNS servers
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue today and contacted Heroku support. They had me delete the ~/.heroku directory. That solved the issue!

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't work for me. I have also contacted support. They haven't managed to come up with a solution yet, other than changing my DNS manually

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a DNS issue, unrelated to Heroku CLI.
I would double-check your DNS settings to ensure that you are able to resolve that url. For example, you might find that you get the same error if you get
`nslookup d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net` or `ping d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net`.

Comment: Actually ping is responding. `ping d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net
PING d1gvo455cekpjp.cloudfront.net (54.230.128.235) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server-54-230-128-235.ams50.r.cloudfront.net (54.230.128.235): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=32.6 ms
64 bytes from server-54-230-128-235.ams50.r.cloudfront.net (54.230.128.235): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=33.6 ms`

Comment: Woah, in that case, can you try flushing your DNS? I saw someone else mention that working for them for a similar error message. We're just about officially over my head at this point. (That's what I get for thinking this was an "easy" one :)

Comment: That doesn't help either. I have contacted support. Hopefully they have an answer